# OpenInviter not importing contacts from Hotmail

Tags: php, html

I am using OpenInviter (Version 1.9.6) to import contacts from Gmail, Yahoo, and Hotmail.

All of them were working well last month, but now I am unable to import any contacts from Hotmail.

I am also having problems importing some Yahoo contacts. I tried http://svetlozar.net/address-book-importer-demo.html, but it's giving me the same error for the specific Yahoo contacts that are giving me problems:

```
Login Failed. Please Check Your Email-Id and Password you have provided
```

Answer (score 5):

Most of the scripts including **Openinviter** dont really work properly or sometimes doesnt work at all, relying on such scripts is not a good idea. So i would suggest using oAuth (where available) or specific apis provided by the Service Providers,
Like

- For Gmail, you could use [Google Contacts Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/)
- For Yahoo, you could use [Yahoo Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contact_api.html)
- For Hotmail/Live you could use [Windows Live Contacts API](http://livecontactsphp.codeplex.com/)

Hope it helps you in finding some way.

Answer (score 0):

OpenInviter has not kept up with the changes that have been happening to Hotmail/MSN/Live/Outlook.com

CloudSponge has a great PHP library for this:
https://github.com/cloudsponge/cloudsponge-lib-php/

You can see the user experience for yourself here:
http://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive

Please let me know how you like it.

Disclaimer (in case it wasn't obvious): I work for CloudSponge.